# Retaining boolean value (or variables in general) even if UIViewController deallocated

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5

I have a UIViewController (firstViewController) which has a button that 'segue's to another UIViewController (secondViewController). The first time secondViewController appears I want a UIAlertView to appear. Now I thought this would be easy at first - I thought i'd just create a boolean variable and set it to 1 after the UIAlertView is displayed for the first time. However I now realise that everytime the user hits back (to firstViewControllerand) and then again clicks on the button to display secondViewController, the boolean variable is reinitialized.

What's the best practice for this sort of thing?

Thanks for any help!

Alex

Comment: Look into global variables, I think that may be what you need...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a great use case for [`NSUserDefaults`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html). This allows you to store `BOOL`s or `int`, `float`, `NSString`, `NSDate`, etc in a conveniently accessible way.

Set the `BOOL` using

```
NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"seenIt"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

and retrieve it using

```
NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
BOOL seenIt = [defaults boolForKey:@"seenIt"];
```

Comment: @PengOne The difference in my answer was that  I did not see your's until after I posted, it was not a copy even though rather similar. But since my answer is superfluous I have deleted it.

Comment: @CocoaFu I didn't think it was a copy, just thought I genuinely missed something.

Comment: @PengOne No problem, no offense taken. It really would have been better to have deleted it when I say yours.

Answer (score 0):

though the other solution works , i would use a much easier solution i.e

just add another C Header file called constants and initialize an Integer variable

```
int buttonPressed;
```

then in the firstViewController

```
#include constants.h
```

on button pressed methood

```
buttonPressed =buttonpressed+1;
```

then in secondViewController

```
#include Constants.h

if(buttonPressed==1)
{
 ///Show alert View
}
```